# How to get pre-defined value labels in the gtsummary-table?

Tags: r, spss, gtsummary

So I got this big database that was exported from SPSS. (Be aware I'm an R-rookie.) All the categorical data was stored under the 'dbl+lbl'-class. I redefined it to the factor class with this code:

```
#a value to define all dbl+lbl-variables:
dbl_lbl_cols <- which(sapply(df_relevant, function(x) inherits(x, "haven_labelled")))

#changing of the classes:
df_relevant[, dbl_lbl_cols] <- lapply(df_relevant[, dbl_lbl_cols], as_factor)
```

When I use the `attributes`-function I see that the levels all have a value label, as in the example below:

```
> attributes(df_relevant$Age_per_ten_years)$labels
       18-29        30-39        40-49        50-59        60-69        70-79        80-89 90 and older 
           1            2            3            4            5            6            7            8
```

Now when making a gtsummary-table, I become a nice table. It, however, uses the numeric data instead of the value labels. See following code and an [image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hak8X.png). (Data is redacted due to the confidentiality of the study.) The eight age categories are further sub-divided by sex.

```
tbl_summary_labelled <- df_relevant %>%
  select(Sex, Age_per_ten_years, Heart_failure_comorbidity, Weight) %>%
   
  tbl_strata(Age_per_ten_years, ~
                tbl_summary(
                 .x,
                  by=Sex,
                  label= list( Age_per_ten_years = "Age categories", 
                               Heart_failure_comorbidity ~ "Heart failure", 
                               Weight ~ "Weight in kilograms"),
                  statistic= all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                  missing_text = "Missing",
                 type = list(Heart_failure_comorbidity ~ "dichotomous")
                ) %>%
                bold_labels()
                
)

print(tbl_summary_labelled)
```

Up to this point, I haven't found anything in the documentation nor on this site how I can show the value labels instead of the categorical level values. For the dichotomous variables like the heart failure comorbidity I can get around this by just telling R I'll want to show these by the dichotomous gtsummary-type, but for those like age and sex (where the data gets stratified with; variables in the column), or BMI (variables in the row) the problem stays.

Looking forward to your reply and thanks in advance!

Comment: To get the most from this site, please include code we can run on our machines, which includes data. You can often find public data or even create a small dataset to illustrate your issue. Regarding your question, I would call `haven::as_factor()` on your entire dataset to convert all incompatible classes, then pass to the gtsummary functions